# ggplot2 how to get a monochromatic scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with plenty of columns, the first one is datetimes and the rest are a path of stock prices. I intend to plot them all at once so I can see what the overall simulation does. To do this, I used:

```
y %>%
 melt(id.vars = "hora",
      variable.name = "series" ) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = hora, y = value))+
 geom_line(aes(color = series))+
 xlab("")+
 ylab("")+
 theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Where y is my dataframe, "hora" is the datetime, "series" is each column of the original dataframe and "value" would be the stock price. This allowed me to plot all the stock prices at once.

[image: Plotting all stock price simulations]

You can replicate a similar dataset with:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(reshape2)

price.path <- function(p, t, meanr, sdr){
  score <- c(0,rt(t, 3))
  retorno <- meanr + sdr*score
  prices <- p*exp(cumsum(retorno))
}

start_date <- today() + hms("9:30:00")
end_date <- today() + hms("16:00:00")
n <- interval(start_date,end_date)/minutes(5)-1
f <- start_date + 5*minutes(0:n)


p <- map(seq(1,100),
    ~price.path(
      p = 20,
      t = n,
      meanr = 0.00005,
      sdr = 0.0002))
y <- map_dfc(p, `[`)
y <- cbind(hora = f, y)
```

This worked as intended, but now I want to make this more pleasing to the eye. Since no particular path is relevant, I tried to give all lines the same color, but this broke the graph:

```
y %>%
  melt(id.vars = "hora",
       variable.name = "series" ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hora, y = value))+
  geom_line(color = "red")+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

(Any explanation onto why this happened is welcomed.)

I figured the best approach would be to use a monochromatic color scale (eg: colors ranging from a light blue to a darker blue), assigning one color in such scale to any individual path. But this was way harder than I expected, using scale_color_gradient() didn't work because

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

I found some color palettes that worked like viridis, but such color palettes did not mix well with my desired graph.

I found that scale_color_hue() gave something kinda similar to what I wanted, but it changed the hue while fixing the lightness, whereas I want to keep the hue while changing the hue.

Also, scale_color_grey() worked pretty well too, but I want my graph to have a little more color. It would be nice if I could add some parameter to this function so it adds a color:

[image]

Any kind of help would be appreciated, if the way I tried to plot all the columns in the dataframe is not efficient I would also like to know, thanks in advance.

Comment: For your red graph, add `ggplot(aes(x = hora, y = value, group = series))+
  geom_line(color = "red")+`... so that each series is plotted separately. As is, the series are all being combined in the plotting.

Comment: With so many lines, add `alpha = 0.2` to what @JonSpring said.

Comment: really helpful guys,  thanks